# rPath clone or similar

Tags: linux, rhel, configuration

I just joined a new company, and this company is using [rPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPath) in its system deployment process.

If you did not know, rPath as a company and solution, has been closed and discontinued when they were acquired by SAS.

Is there any similar solution like rPath, or a straight clone for that solution?

RPath use the model of "package version snapshot", which for a given day, you can get a snapshot of operating system package that should be working correctly. With that base snapshot, you can create other set of group (eg. web server, mail server, VNC, etc) that sit on top of that, to create a fully working environment. With that version defined, you can go to any machine that subscribe to the snapshot and the group, and do "migration" that will automatically resolve and install the dependencies. If it have errors, you can roll back the installation, and get the last working version.

Comment: What does rPath do, and most importantly, what do you use it for?

Comment: rPath use the model of "package version snapshot", which for a given day, you can get a snapshot of operating system package that should be working correctly. With that base snapshot, you can create other set of group (eg. web server, mail server, VNC, etc) that sit on top of that, to create a fully working environment. With that version defined, you can go to any machine that subscribe to the snapshot and the group, and do "migration" that will automatically resolve and install the dependencies. If it have errors, you can roll back the installation, and get the last working version

Comment: Well, Foresight Linux distribution uses `Conary` (http://www.foresightlinux.org/). Since it uses the same package manager, some of the snapshots/rollback features could be available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, there are no visible rPath clone out there.

If you are using rPath for package management and using Red Hat in your environment and would like to transition away, the logical tool for the task is Red Hat Satellite.

If you are adventurous, you can try Spacewalk, which is the Open Source upstream version of Red Hat Satellite.